# How to set expire time for CookieService in Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I m using the ngx-cookie-service package . I can set, get, delete, deleteall cookie but how I set the expire time for cookie so that it automatically expire/delete after that time interval.

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at its github [link](https://github.com/7leads/ngx-cookie-service#readme) example of `set` method.
Which is

`set( name: string, value: string, expires?: number | Date, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean ): void;`

So you have the third optional parameter of expiry

Answer (score 0):

I have coding for setting expire time:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

   private cookieExpireTime: Date;

   constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {
   }

   // Set time expired
   setCookieExpireTime() {
       let expireTime = 'your_time';
       this.cookieExpireTime = new Date(expireTime * 1000);
   }

   // Get time expired 
   getCookieExpireTime(): Date {
       return this.cookieExpireTime;
   }

   // Delete
   deleteTimeExpired(){
      this.cookieService.delete('expiredtime');
   }

   // Set time expired for token
   setTokenCookie(data: any) {
       this.cookieService.set('token_store', JSON.stringify(data), this.getCookieExpireTime());
   }

}
```

I hope that this code can help you.